# javafx 7" touchscreen blanking

Tags: touchscreen, javafx

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 3 and the official 7" touchscreen. The goal is to run a JavaFX application that serves as a central point to control home automation services.

While everything seems to work at first sight, I notice a problem with screen blanking. When the screen blanks while the raspbian desktop is shown, the screen can be activated again by simply touching it. However, when the screen blanks when the JavaFX application is running, the screen can not be activated anymore. When I kill the application over SSH, the screen can be activated again.

I know I could disable the screen blanking, but given the usecase, I do not like the screen to be active 24/7 and would like it to blank after a couple of minutes.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Many thanks in advance!